# Is it possible to convert a Jetpack extension to a chrome one?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to convert a FF Jetpack extension to a chrome's one? I've read something about wrappers but I don't know if they have already implemented one.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In general, extensions based on the Firefox Add-on SDK are more powerful - [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) gives them access to all browser internals, a level of access that Chrome extensions simply don't have. Even if you only look at the API provided by the SDK, it is different enough from Chrome's extension API that any kind of generic conversion is impossible. However, often you can convert an extension manually but reimplementing the necessary parts.

Comment: +1 Very complete answer. That's what I did. In fact my extension was easier to implement in a chrome extension because in FF Jetpack I couldn't figure out how to make cross-domain post requests from the content-scripts so I had to do it from the main lib and then comunicate with them. In contrast, in chrome I just added permissions for the target site and got the posts directly from the content script.